# Mean value inequality for multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and has bounded derivatives. Consider the difference operator $T_{y}$ defined by $(T_{y}f)(x) = f(x+y)-f(x)$. If $y_{1},...,y_{N}$ are given, we denote the composite maps $T_{y_{1}}\circ \cdots \circ T_{y_{N}}$ simply by $T_{y_{1},...,y_{N}}$. By the Mean Value Theorem, I know that:
$$|(T_{y}f)(x)| = |f(x+y)-f(x)| \le \|\nabla f\|_{\infty}\|y\| \le C \|y\|$$
for some constante $C$. I'm trying to get an analogous formula for multiple interactions of the difference operator, that is, I'm trying to obtain upper bounds for $|(T_{y_{1},...,y_{N}}f)(x)|$. My intuition says I have to apply $N$ times the triangular inequality, so I'd have something like:
$$|(T_{y_{1},...,y_{N}}f)(x)| \le C \sum_{i=1}^{N}\|y_{i}\|,$$
but I couldn't prove it with details (I don't even know if this is accurate). Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $T_i=T_{y_i}$ and $\tau_n=T_nT_{n-1}\dots T_1$. What you have shown
   is that $$ |T_ig| \le C|y_i|$$ for any function with$|\nabla g|\le
   C. $ Then since$^*$ $|\nabla T_1f|\le2C$, generally $|\nabla \tau_k
   f|\le 2^kC$, $$ |\tau_n f|=|T_n\tau_{n-1}f|\le 2^{n-1}C|y_n|.$$
2. Note that
   $$T_1T_2f(x)=T_1(f(x+y_2)-f(x))=f(x+y_1+y_2)-f(x+y_1)-f(x+y_2)+f(x)$$
   is left unchanged when you exchange $y_1$ and $y_2$. Inductively $\tau_n$ does not depend on the order of the $T_i$s. Hence for any $i$,
   $$ |\tau_n f|\le2^{n-1}C|y_i|.$$
   Thus,
   $$  |\tau_n f|\le2^{n-1}C\min_{i=1}^n|y_i|\le \frac{2^{n-1}C}n\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|.$$

---

$^*$ You cannot improve the factor 2 in general, since it is possible that $f(x+y)=-f(x)$ (e.g. $f=\sin$ and $y$ a half period.